# How can I get real process same as sparkWebUi

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

How can I get real process same as sparkWebUi

Comment: I am having a hard time trying to understand your question. Could you please add some examples of what you want to get?

Comment: I want to get JobNum when spark start, through completeTask/taks*jobNum get process; but i feel it not best method.